# How to emulate mouseover or run JS function on page with PhantomJS in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

**NodeJS, PhantomJS, content parsing with Cheerio**

Need to parse webpage, that contains dynamically loaded div(hint). The event can be on many table td's, here is an example

[image]

When I 'mouseover' on specific td I see this orange block with data, it's dynamically loaded with function, like this

```
onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','355svxv498x0x0',417,event,0,1)"
```

I can view this info only after the page is loaded. Need to a specific row, only Marathonbet.

When the function runs, the text is loaded into another div (id='tooltip') and shown to the user.

I use phantom to parse the content of this page, everything OK with static values, but how I can receive this dynamically generated block to my rendered web page inside node router?
I see 2 ways:

1. Emulate mouse move on this coordinates to show needed text, but
   there is a problem, how I can known it's coords?
2. Emulate function start after page is loaded and i known they codes
   ('355svxv498x0x0',417), but how I can run this function from node, 
   from phantom?

   Here is some code, that recieve static page content in my router

```

```
phantom.create(config.phantomParams).then(ph => {
    _ph = ph;
    return _ph.createPage();
}).then(page => {
    _page = page;
    return _page.on('onConsoleMessage', function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
}).then(() => {
    return _page.on('viewportSize', {width: 1920, height: 1080});
}).then(() => {
    return _page.on('dpi', 130)
}).then(() => {
    _page.setting('userAgent', config.userAgent);
    return _page.open(matchLink);
}).then(() => {
    return _page.property('content');
}).then(content => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(content);

    // working with content and get needed elements

    console.log($.html());
}).then(() => {
    _page.close();
    _ph.exit();
});
```

```
Should I use Casper/Spooky, or anyone can explain how to use it in this case?

UPD. Trying with puppeteer, the code

```

```
let matchLink = 'http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/world/club-friendly/san-carlos-guadalupe-xnsUg7zB/';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [
            '--proxy-server=46.101.167.43:80',
        ]});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await browser.userAgent(config.userAgent);
    await page.setViewport({width: 1440, height: 960});
    await page.goto(matchLink);
    await page.evaluate(() => page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','355svxv464x0x7omg7',381,event,0,1));

    let bodyHTML = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);

    console.log(bodyHTML);
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

    await browser.close();
})();
```

```

Get
```

```
(node:8591) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined
    at toolTip (http://www.oddsportal.com/res/x/global-180713073352.js:1:145511)
    at TableSet.historyTooltip (http://www.oddsportal.com/res/x/global-180713073352.js:1:631115)
    at PageEvent.PagePrototype.hist (http://www.oddsportal.com/res/x/global-180713073352.js:1:487314)
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:13
    at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (/home/gil/Projects/oddsbot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:97:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

```

Error in target JS file, may be something with request..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're open to suggestions I propose [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/) It's a native node.js module that opens pages in the newest Chromium (especially useful since PhantomJS is very outdated) and is close to PhantomJS in terms of doing thinkgs.

If you also use node.js 8.x, async/await syntax is available for working with promises and it makes scraping with puppeteer a breeze.

So to run that function in puppeteer you would run

```
await page.evaluate(() => page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','355svxv498x0x0',417,event,0,1) );
```

**Update**

Puppeteer has lots of convenience helpers, one of them is [page.hover](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagehoverselector) that literally will hover a pointer over an element:

```
await page.hover('td.some_selector');
```

---

But should you want to continue using Phantomjs and the excellent `phantom` module, you can:

```
_page.evaluate(function() {
    page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','355svxv498x0x0',417,event,0,1)
})
```

Documents on `page.evaluate`: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html

Comment: Try to do this with puppeteer, but recieve `(node:8591) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined
`

Comment: `page.hist` probably depends on the event target. Updated the answer

Comment: Seems to be the good decision, but on this page there are no unique selectors on this divs in table like `<td><div onmouseout="delayHideTip()" onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','355svxv464x0x7omg8',381,event,0,1)">2.20</div></td>` And i don't know which div i should hover when page opens, when i give any other selector (for example of table) i receive the same error with `stopPropagation of undefined`

Comment: Try to run the script with Chromium visible `puppeteer.launch({headless : false})` and Devtools open, that can help a lot.