# Displaying text from onmouseover attribute with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver, onmouseover

Different versions of this question have already been asked:

[How can I locate a onmouseover element using Selenium in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724475/how-can-i-locate-a-onmouseover-element-using-selenium-in-python/53136787#53136787)

[How to emulate mouseover or run JS function on page with PhantomJS in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51321207/how-to-emulate-mouseover-or-run-js-function-on-page-with-phantomjs-in-nodejs)

Basically what I want to do is to get the text from a table cell that displays when the mouse is over, as seen in the image below. I code in Python and use Beautiful Soup

[image]

I can successfully get the onmouseover attribute using Beautiful Soup:

```
<td class="right odds down"><div onmouseout="delayHideTip()" onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','357osx2s5a4x0x7ot9r',2,event,0,1)">+340</div></td>  

<div onmouseout="delayHideTip()" onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','357osx2s5a4x0x7ot9r',2,event,0,1)">+340</div>
```

My question is. How can I get the text (the initial odd) using the attribute:

```
onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-0.00-0-0','357osx2s5a4x0x7ot9r',2,event,0,1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the answer is actually to get the information with Selenium webdriver. 
For example if we want to get initial odds from bwin, which the 8th row in our odds-data-table: 
its x-path is:

```
 "//*[@id =" + '"odds-data-table"' + "]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]")
```

and we can retrieve the initial odd data by first hovering over it and getting the info as such:

```
 initial_odd_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id =" + '"odds-data-table"' + "]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]")
hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(initial_odd_data)
hov.perform()
data_in_the_bubble = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tooltiptext']")
hover_data = data_in_the_bubble.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```